# jquery ui css class not triggered

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

What is the difference between updating a existing css with a new class using the following method?

```
method 1:

 create:function () {
    $(this).closest(".ui-dialog").find(".ui-button").addClass('custom');
    }


method 2:

  $('#divUI').find('.ui-button').addClass('cancelButton');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DOmEl/AvF8V/3/

The first method works fine in my local site. The second method works fine in fiddle but not in my local site.

so anyone has idea why the second method not working in my local site but in fiddle?

Comment: only reason is the selector `$('#divUI')` might be wrong

Comment: I used the same code that provided in fiddle.

Comment: $("#divparent").find('.ui-button').addClass('cancelButton'); works fine. confused..